# How to access the files in kaha db

Tags: database

As the kaha db used to store the persistent data is there any method to access the un consumed files in the db. Please suggest with some of the UI through which the data in the kaha db can be accessed, Is there any method to use some queries to access the data from kaha db. please help me out to get with a solution.

Is there any query browser used to query kaha db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kaha db is an in memory database used with Activemq to store the queuing data. It stores the files in the form of journal files with a Btree index made on every journal file it stores. On my finding no query browsers are available to query the kaha db but there are options to access the jornal files of the kahadb which stores the data.

Comment: Check this link : https://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-monitor-activemq.html
There are some tools that provides a way to read a kahadb

Answer (score 1):

unable to find any UI way to access it rather we can make use of the below amq-kahadb-tool to see what's inside and a summary of the kaha db logs

https://github.com/Hill30/amq-kahadb-tool

Comment: Really good tool (KahaDBJournalsReader.jar) for dumping content. It dumps entire content with all messages present in the file including already consumed. So you must match KAHA_ADD_MESSAGE_COMMAND with KAHA_REMOVE_MESSAGE_COMMAND by messageId to understand if the message has been already consumed or not.